# Fetch multiple data from firebase and store it in table

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm trying to fetch multiple data from firebase and store it in table but the value that I'm getting is null below is my code

Index.html

```
<!Doctype html>

<html>

    <title>Back-end</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css "href="style.css">

    <body>
        <div class="main">

        <button class = "btn" type="button">Login</button>

            <div class="nav">

            </div>

            <div class = "reports">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Address</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Phone</td>
                            <td>Total</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id = "table_body">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>  

        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.1/firebase.js"></script>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {

var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyATKzdugFp6bFy_vvxiwAdC_d_s-eS6-FM",
    authDomain: "itsproject-d842d.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://itsproject-d842d.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "itsproject-d842d",
    storageBucket: "itsproject-d842d.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "919597385149"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const req = document.getElementById('Requests');

  const dbRefReq = firebase.database().ref().child('Requests')

  dbRefReq.on('value', snap => {

      const address = snap.child("address").val();
      const name = snap.child("name").val();
      const phone = snap.child("phone").val();
      const total = snap.child("total").val();

      $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + address + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + phone + "</td><td>" + total +"</td></tr>");

  });

  }());
```

Here's what I'm fetching and the result: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple requests under `/Requests`, and your code fails to handle that. So you're now essentially adding the value `/Requests/address` to the HTML, and since that node doesn't exist, the value is empty.

To handle the extra level of your HTML, either listen for `on("child_added"` or loop over the child nodes:

```
dbRefReq.on('value', snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    const address = snap.child("address").val();
    const name = snap.child("name").val();
    const phone = snap.child("phone").val();
    const total = snap.child("total").val();

    $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + address + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + phone + "</td><td>" + total +"</td></tr>");
  });
});
```

Comment: how about fetching data from my "Request".child sir? i have tried doing const dbref = dbRefReq.child("foods"); then i did the same as my request but im getting null